# Why am I receiving the error 'Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed'?

Tags: java, sql, database, arraylist

I have an sql database where I am attempting to load data from. RstImport Student is importing from the student table which contains firstName, middleName, lastName, phoneNumber and dob. RstImportModule is then importing from the moduleslist table which contains 6 modules and grades. The imported data from each is then used to create a new student object, with the modules and grades being added to an array in this object. The student object should then be added to the listOfStudents arraylist. I am receiving the error 'Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed'. When debugging eclipse is telling me there is an error occurring at the start of the second while loops. Why am I receiving this error?

```
public class LoadData {

public static ArrayList<Student> loadStudentData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Statement stm = null;

    System.out.println("Connecting to Database");
    System.out.println("**********************");

    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection
            ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/schoolstudentsystem", "root", "");

    stm = myConn.createStatement();

    String sqlImportStudent = "Select * From students";
    String sqlImportModule = "Select * From moduleslist";

    ResultSet rstImportStudent = stm.executeQuery(sqlImportStudent);
    ResultSet rstImportModule = stm.executeQuery(sqlImportModule);

    ModuleGrade[] moduleGradeArray = new ModuleGrade[6];

    while (rstImportModule.next()) {

        for(int i = 0; i < Student.modulesList.length; i++) {

            ModuleGrade mg1 = new ModuleGrade(rstImportModule.getString("m1"), rstImportModule.getInt("mg1"));
            ModuleGrade mg2 = new ModuleGrade(rstImportModule.getString("m2"), rstImportModule.getInt("mg2"));
            ModuleGrade mg3 = new ModuleGrade(rstImportModule.getString("m3"), rstImportModule.getInt("mg3"));
            ModuleGrade mg4 = new ModuleGrade(rstImportModule.getString("m4"), rstImportModule.getInt("mg4"));
            ModuleGrade mg5 = new ModuleGrade(rstImportModule.getString("m5"), rstImportModule.getInt("mg5"));
            ModuleGrade mg6 = new ModuleGrade(rstImportModule.getString("m6"), rstImportModule.getInt("mg6"));

            moduleGradeArray[0] = mg1;
            moduleGradeArray[1] = mg2;
            moduleGradeArray[2] = mg3;
            moduleGradeArray[3] = mg4;
            moduleGradeArray[4] = mg5;
            moduleGradeArray[5] = mg6;

                }
        while (rstImportStudent.next()) {

            Student student = new Student(rstImportStudent.getString("firstName"), rstImportStudent.getString("middleName"), 
                    rstImportStudent.getString("lastName"), 
                    rstImportStudent.getString("email"), rstImportStudent.getString("phoneNumber"), rstImportStudent.getInt("dob"),
                    moduleGradeArray);

                    ClassGroup.listOfStudents.add(student);     

                }
        }

    rstImportStudent.close();
    rstImportModule.close();
    myConn.close();

    return ClassGroup.listOfStudents;

}

}
```

Comment: Create two `Statement` objects - one for each query.

Comment: From [the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html): *By default, only one ResultSet object per Statement object can be open at the same time. Therefore, if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects. All execution methods in the Statement interface implicitly close a current ResultSet object of the statement if an open one exists.*

Comment: @JBNizet thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

If you call close on a statement it will automatically close the Con from whence it came as well.

Are you getting the error here?

```
rstImportStudent.close();
rstImportModule.close();
myConn.close();
```

What if there is an exception before you close? You should be using try with resources.

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding a second statement object. However you are correct I must add exception handling, thank you

Comment: Don't forget to use "try with resources" instead of a regular try catch so you don't have to try and close stuff in the catch block.